# Is there in assembler the special symbol which indicate on line break in source code?

Tags: masm, masm32

I have too large const, but masm don't compile my source code. How can I fix it?

```
C25 byte 51, 135, 173, 160, 231, 165, 173, 168, 165, 32, 162, 235, 224, 160, 166, 165, 173, 168, 239, 32, 115, 117, 109, 91, 49, 48, 48, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 48, 93, 32, 109, 111, 100, 32, 49, 53, 48, 48, 32, 100, 105, 118, 32, 51, 58, 32
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXfG0.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put at most 48 elements per line. So split the line into two or more lines that each contains 48 elements or less, e.g.:

```
C25 byte 51, 135, 173, 160, 231, 165, 173, 168, 165, 32, 162, 235, 224, 160, 166, 165, 173, 168, 239, 32, 115, 117, 109, 91, 49
    byte 48, 48, 48, 44, 32, 49, 48, 48, 48, 93, 32, 109, 111, 100, 32, 49, 53, 48, 48, 32, 100, 105, 118, 32, 51, 58, 32
```